# Run function only if file is really downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, filesaver.js

I need to run a function, only if the file really gets downloaded.

It means, that I want to run a function only when the popup window of "download" is confirmed, when clicked "Cancel" nothing happens.

I am using fileSaver.js like this:

```
var blob = new Blob([content], {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
});
saveAs(blob, filename);
run_this();
```

Is there a way of achieving the confirmation of download?

Comment: In the event handler for the download button, download the file and then execute the function.  In the event handler for the cancel button don't do either.  Sorry, but what is the question here?

Comment: The question is how to detect dynamicaly generated file downloading. Maybe I dont understand your solution, but download button triggers the pop-up window and that window contains its buttons "save" and "cancel" and I am reffering to them

Comment: Okay - so you want to know if the user saved the file when they were presented with the save dialog.  There's no way to detect that, that I know of.  The alternative is to have a download link with the `download` attribute.  That doesn't show the save dialog - it just saves.

Comment: that is unfortunate to hear, it is neccesery to show the dialog. Anyway thank you, I will keep searching for the answer.